# what's the login for web apps deployedin Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have a very simple web app created in visual studio and ran perfectly fine locally [image]After I published in Azure from VS using public profiles. I was asked to register like this [image]. I was trying to sign up and it shows: [image]. So how can I get around this authentication stuff?

Comment: You need to figure out what the error is. Add error logging etc. And if you don't want user accounts in your application, don't add Identity!

Comment: Firstly, you can create/set ``<customErrors mode="Off"/>`` in your web.config file. Secondly, please make sure if your database connection string is correct.

Comment: @mason how did I add Identity? If I did how can remove them?

Comment: When you created the project in VS, did you pay attention to the Authentication options? You chose "Individual User Accounts" which adds Identity. You likely should have chosen "No Authentication". You'll have to manually do a bunch of cleanup if you want to remove it  from a created project: remove NuGet packages, deleting models and controllers and views related to Identity etc.

Comment: @mason, I've fount that button you were talking about. However, it's gray when I try to create the application. (single-page Application) so where is the correct login information. Or how did I sign up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a ASP.NET Single Page Application (with **Individual User Accounts** as the authentication), if you check your Web.config file, you will find a connection string named `DefaultConnection` is added, which points to a LocalDb instance.

[image]

After you publish your application to Azure app service web app, as I mentioned in my comment, if you create `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in your web.config file to see the details error message, you will find a database related issue cause the error.  The error may look like:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

If possible, you can try to [create a Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal), and update your Web.config connection string using that Azure SQL database.